# Is the zero subspace 0 independent with any other subspace (of vector space) (Linear algebra hoffman)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Recall Definition:** (in sec 6.6 on 209p)

Let $W_1,...,W_k$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. We say that $W_1,...,W_k$ are **independent** if $\alpha_1+...+\alpha_k=0$, $\alpha_i \in W_i$ implies that each $\alpha_i$ is $0$.

**Question:**

By this definition, I think the zero subspace $0$ is independent of all subspace of $V$. Am I right? Or is there a problem?

Comment: To be precise: If you have a collection of subspaces, adding the zero subspace to the collection does not change the dependence/independence. Your definition really doesn't talk about one subspace being "independent of" another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{ #1 \}}$Yes.

Let $\set{W_i}_{i=1}^n$ be an arbitrary finite family of subspaces of $V$ which are independent. Consider along with them the trivial space $Z := \set{\vec 0}$. I claim that $\set Z \cup \set{W_i}_{i=1}^n$ is an independent family of spaces. Indeed, take $w_i \in W_i$ and $z \in Z$, and consider the combination

$$S := z + w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_n$$

Since the $W_i$ are independent, and $z \in Z \iff z = \vec 0$, it immediately follows $S \equiv 0$ always.

In particular, if the family in question is a singleton, i.e. it only consists of a single space $\set{W}$, then $W$ is independent from $Z$ and $\set{W,Z}$ are a family of independent subspaces of the vector space $V$.